# Compute sum of edges in paths from source to target node?

Tags: dynamic-programming

Given a directed acyclic graph G = (V,E). Suppose that the vertices are in topological sort, in particular there exist an edge $(u,v) \in E$ if u <v (see the graph below). The weight $w(u,v)$ on each edge is a positive number. For a given node $i$, I am interested in computing the  following term $s[i]$ defined as follows:
s[i] is sum of weights on any edges (w.o duplicates) of some paths from the source node 1 to the node i.
For example, in the below graph s[6] =  3+ 2+ 10 + 20 + 200 + 100 = 335.
I am struggling how to come up with a linear time w.r.t $|V|$ and $|E|$ to compute $s[i]$ for a given node $i$.

I am thinking of using dynamic programing. For example, suppose we already can compute $s[j]$ up to $j<k$, to compute $s[k]$ we might attempt $s[k] = \sum_{i} s[i] + w[i,k]$ if there is an edge $(i,k)$. For example, to compute $s[6]$ we need $s[4]$ and $s[5]$,

So $s[6] = (s[4] + 200) + ( s[5]+ 100) = (3+200) + ( (3+2+20+2+10) +100) $ but this approach fails since we did not take into account that  the edge $(1,4)$ is shared in computing $s[4]$ and $s[5]$. The edge $(1,4)$ should be summed one time in $s[6]$.

[image: Example of graph]

Comment: (`there exist an edge (u,v)∈E if u <v (see the graph below)` to see that, I have to mentally add a lot of edges of inconsequential weight (0?) to immediately forget about them.) (The first $+\ 2$ is extraneous in the example)

Comment: The vertices being topologically sorted is not equivalent to there being an edge if $(u,v)$ if $u<v$.  Your example graph does not satisfy the latter condition; for instance, there is no edge $(1,2)$.

Comment: Can you tell us about the motivation for this problem, or the context where you encountered it?  Was it an exercise? If so, can you credit the original source (e.g., textbook) and tell us about what you've been studying most recently?

Comment: This question from qualifying exam that I need to practice. Another idea that comes into my mind right now is
We can perform BFS search and collect all simple paths from the source node 1 to the destination node 6.  Whenever we find one simple path, we store all edges of this simple path into a hash map. If there is one edge which already existed in the hash map, then we skip that edge.
Finally, the hash map contains only all edges without duplication of paths from source (1) to destination (e.g 6). So we just need to compute sum of all these edges.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach that should work w/out need for a hash table is as follows:

Let two boolean arrays $a,b$ such that

- $a[u] =1 $ iff a path $1 \ldots u$ exists
- $b[u] =1$ if a path $u  \ldots i$ exists

Both can be calculated in $O(V+E)$ time : $a$ with a simple BFS from $1$, and $b$ by a bottom-up approach of examining the vertices in the reverse topological order.

Now, you consider each edge of the graph $ u \rightarrow v$ and add $w(u,v)$  to the answer iff $a[u]=1$ and $b[v]=1$.
Because the graph is a DAG the two paths above must be disjoint thus their concatenation is a valid path from $1$ to $i$ and since we consider each edge once, there are no duplicates.

Comment: Great solution ! I liked your ideas.

Comment: @XieYao There is help on [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)